# user instance login flag is not supported on this version of sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created an Asp.net website using VS 2008 and SQL Express 2008 on one PC. with db files in |Data Directory|.
When i copied these website files to another PC ( having same VS 2008 and SQL Express 2008) its giving me error
user instance login flag is not supported on this version of sql server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you 100% certain that the new environment is indeed Express?

If so, you may need to configure the server to allow user instance connections. If you have admin access, you can run this command.

```
-- Enable user instances.
sp_configure 'user instances enabled','1' 

-- Disable user instances.
sp_configure 'user instances enabled','0'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx

If not, then SQL Server (full or non-Express versions) does not support the "user instance" (i.e. automatic creation of databases / attaching from user code) directive in the connection string.  It's a feature of SQL Server Express edition.

Comment: no its not working. I got it working by running aspnet_sqlreg

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by removing `User Instance=true;`